# using AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne to add delay before executing a line in C#

Tags: c#

I want to execute a function after some 2 seconds delay in C#

I tried the below code

```
IAsyncResult result;
Action action = () =>
{
    //I want to call my function here after 1 second delay
    Console.WriteLine("Delayed logging");
};

result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500000))
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("done");
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xvo3UK)

I just want to navigate to a different page after showing some alert message to user

Comment: Just as @Ðаn mentioned, you should probably `Thread.Sleep(1000);`

Comment: here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QwGlvX) with a time measurement. with the already 3 times proposed sleep version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already proposed, you can use the [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) method to delay your call:

```
public static void Main()
{

    IAsyncResult result;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Action action = () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //I want to call my function here after 1 second delay
        Console.WriteLine("Delayed logging");
    };

    result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500000))
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("done");

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

Output:

> Delayed logging
>   Completed
>   1000

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a lot more to what you're actually trying to do, messing around with `IAsyncResult`, `Action`, and `BeginInvoke` is massive overkill. All you need to do is:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
// call your funcction
```

Comment: He's most likely adding the delay just to test the async stuff.